# How to append Json file inside php using Php

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I have an json file embedded inside php file,  I would like to add new infromation from form inside json file...

My form is

```html
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
 First name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="firstName">
 <br><br/>
 Last name:<br>
 <input type="text" name="lastName">
 <br><br>
   
 Email:<br>
 <input type="text" name="email">
 <br><br>
   
 Mobile:<br>
 <input type="text" name="mobile">
 <br><br>
   
   
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and the php file is

```html
<?php
   
   $myFile = "data.php";
   $arr_data = array(); // create empty array

  try
  {
    //Get form data
    $formdata = array(
       'firstName'=> $_POST['firstName'],
       'lastName'=> $_POST['lastName'],
       'email'=>$_POST['email'],
       'mobile'=> $_POST['mobile']
    );

    //Get data from existing json file
    $jsondata = file_get_contents($myFile);

    // converts json data into array
    $arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    // Push user data to array
    array_push($arr_data,$formdata);

       //Convert updated array to JSON
    $jsondata = json_encode($arr_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
    //write json data into data.json file
    if(file_put_contents($myFile, $jsondata)) {
         echo 'Data successfully saved';
     }
    else 
         echo "error";

   }
   catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
   }

?>
```

When I click the submit button, The new data is being added as follow

```html
{
    "heroes": [
        {
            "firstName": "Vijay",
            "lastName": "reddy",
            "email": "asdv@ymail.com",
            "mobile": ""
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Paki",
            "lastName": "Webb",
            "email": "vahodid@yahoo.com",
            "mobile": "66464646464"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "sagar",
            "lastName": "rawal",
            "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "98989898"
        }
    ],
    "0": {
        "firstName": "sagar",
        "lastName": "rawal",
        "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "98989898"
    },
    "1": {
        "firstName": "Purnima",
        "lastName": "rawal",
        "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
        "mobile": "98652845"
    }
}
```

But I want to have data as

```html
{
    "heroes": [
        {
            "firstName": "Vijay",
            "lastName": "reddy",
            "email": "asdv@ymail.com",
            "mobile": ""
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Paki",
            "lastName": "Webb",
            "email": "vahodid@yahoo.com",
            "mobile": "66464646464"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "sagar",
            "lastName": "rawal",
            "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
            "mobile": "98989898"
        },
        {
           "firstName": "sagar",
           "lastName": "rawal",
           "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
           "mobile": "98989898"
        },
        {
           "firstName": "Purnima",
           "lastName": "rawal",
           "email": "searchbbc1881@gmail.com",
           "mobile": "98652845"
       }
   ]
}
```

i.e remove the index and write the new data inside json along with other data...so far I couldn't do ...so please help me...Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want the data to live in the `heroes` array, then you'll need to add it _to_ that array, not to the object that contains `heroes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just did a array_push to the entire json array, you want it inside 'heroes'

```
// converts json data into array
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$arr_data['heroes'][] = $formdata; // Will push $formdata inside 'heroes' array from json
```

If you prefer to use array_push then do this:

```
// converts json data into array
$arr_data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
array_push($arr_data['heroes'], $formdata); // Will push $formdata inside 'heroes' array from json
```

Comment: but how to push the data on top?? I  used  array_push($arr_data['heroes'][] = $formdata); but it gives me error

Comment: You either do `$arr_data['heroes'][] = $formdata;` or `array_push($arr_data['heroes'],$formdata)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
 array_push($arr_data,$formdata)
```

to this

```
 array_push($arr_data['heroes'],$formdata)
```

Comment: it throws me error "  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$jsondata' (T_VARIABLE) in /srv/disk2/2801471/www/mscphysics.atwebpages.com/test/process.php on line 26 "

Comment: That's because I didn't put the ;, did you remove it?